# Hillel Coren's AutoComplete in Flex 4 doesn't let enter text nor shows list

Tags: apache-flex, autocomplete

Did anybody succeed working with this component in Flex 4? Thanks.

`<hillelcoren:AutoComplete id="blackWhiteListsComplete" matchType="beginning" width="80%" backspaceAction="focus" labelField="name"
allowMultipleSelection="true"/>`

I'm getting:

`Error: FTETextField does not support setting type to "input".
    at mx.core::FTETextField/set type()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\spark\src\mx\core\FTETextField.as:1720]
    at mx.controls::TextInput/commitProperties()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\mx\src\mx\controls\TextInput.as:1790]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/validateProperties()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:8219]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/validateClient()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:957]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/validateNow()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:8077]
    at com.hillelcoren.components::PromptTextInput/setNewText()[C:\Hiro\SVNClientRepos\ManagementV2\branches\3_6_3\common\src\com\hillelcoren\components\PromptTextInput.mxml:246]
    at com.hillelcoren.components::PromptTextInput/commitProperties()[C:\Hiro\SVNClientRepos\ManagementV2\branches\3_6_3\common\src\com\hillelcoren\components\PromptTextInput.mxml:68]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/validateProperties()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:8219]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/validateClient()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:957]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/validateNow()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:8077]
    at com.hillelcoren.components::PromptTextInput/validateNow()[C:\Hiro\SVNClientRepos\ManagementV2\branches\3_6_3\common\src\com\hillelcoren\components\PromptTextInput.mxml:186]
    at com.hillelcoren.components::AutoComplete/set searchText()[C:\Hiro\SVNClientRepos\ManagementV2\branches\3_6_3\common\src\com\hillelcoren\components\AutoComplete.mxml:1246]
    at com.hillelcoren.components::AutoComplete/commitProperties()[C:\Hiro\SVNClientRepos\ManagementV2\branches\3_6_3\common\src\com\hillelcoren\components\AutoComplete.mxml:281]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/validateProperties()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:8219]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/validateProperties()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:597]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiation()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:783]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiationCallback()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:1180]`

Answer (score 1):

This is from a comment on my blog. It doesn't look like he was able to get it working but maybe it'll help you.

http://hillelcoren.com/flex-autocomplete/comment-page-5/#comment-6454

Jonathan says : May 11, 2011 at 8:55 pm
On Flex 4.5:
I found that if you’re using CFF fonts and using the

```
mx|global{
    skinClass: ClassReference("mx.core.UIFTETExtField")
}
```

hack to get CFF fonts working, that autocomplete will NOT work. My temporary workaround is:

```
components|AutoComplete mx|TextInput{
    textFieldClass: ClassReference("mx.core.UITextField");
    fontFamily:verdana;
}
```

This reverts the component to Verdana (A cff/noncff fond) and sets the textfield back to the regular UITextfield.

I believe I could resolve thisin source by switching the text field to the Spark text field which now supports the prompt property, but I haven’t tried that yet.

Jonathan says : May 11, 2011 at 10:26 pm

Actually… i can’t really get this to work very well on 4.5. I’ve downloaded the source and compiled with 4.5 but it’s displaying really funky :(.